# What does a "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction, referenced from:" compile-time error mean?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios

Can anyone please tell me what is this error, I am trying to compile on xcode

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction",
>   referenced from:
>
> ```
>   objc-class-ref-to-CATransaction in RefreshTableViewHeader.o
> ```

And this error

> "_kCATransactionDisableActions",
>   referenced from:
>
> ```
>   _kCATransactionDisableActions$non_lazy_ptr
> ```
>
> in RefreshTableViewHeader.o
>
> ```
>  (maybe you meant: _kCATransactionDisableActions$non_lazy_ptr)
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Google was of no help.

Am I missing any framework...?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a linker error indicating that you're missing some symbols. Try to add QuartzCore framework to link with your project.